# Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "shop-detail"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

im getting error Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "shop-detail"

in file **shop/api/urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('shops', ShopView, base_name='shop')
urlpatterns = [
path('', include(router.urls)),]
```

**file shop/api/serializers.py**

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
    view_name="shop-detail",
    lookup_field='id',)
class Meta:
    model = Shop
    fields = [
        'id',
        'url',
        'name',
    ]
```

what is wrong there? everything works if I dont add 'url' field.

**edit:**

added view code

```
class ShopView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
lookup_field = 'id'
queryset = Shop.objects.all()
serializer_class = ShopSerializer
```

Comment: Can you add ShopView code?

Comment: @neverwalkaloner updated

Comment: to be honest, this should work. Maybe install django extensions, call the show_urls and paste the shop-detail url pattern.

Comment: @Aldon did you get this to work?

Comment: @drec4s yes, i posted a solution, in short just removed lookup_field and it started working

Answer (score 0):

You are registering `shops` so the default name for the detail view will be `shops-detail` while you use `shop-detail`. Note the missing "S"

Fix that with:

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name="shops-detail",
        lookup_field='id',)
```

Comment: did not help,  i think base_name is responsible for that

Comment: oh my... you are absolutely correct. I went a bit too fast on that one, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In [HyperlinkedModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer) by default the serializer will include a *url* field instead of a primary key field. Please see the [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer).

```
class ShopSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Shop
        fields = [
          'id',
          'url',
         'name',
        ]
```

Comment: that exactly how I did before, however I still get the same error with this code

Answer (score 0):

Found a problem, lookup_field in view was not needed.

```
class ShopView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Shop.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShopSerializer
```